# Using command line to copy html file to clipboard

Tags: command-line, 18.04, clipboard, automation

I am trying to do an automated task using Actiona and I need to have the content of an HTML file to be copied into clipboard.
Using the clipboard coding facilities inside Actiona is not a solution while it only uses text DataType (mime type) and I need it to be copied as HTML (text/html).
I'm wondering if I can do it by running a system command in one of the steps.

Comment: Since this is an Q&A site, all answers should be posted in answer section only. For now, I have rolled back your edit. If you found the answer by kabr8 helpful, you can mark that as accepted by clicking on tick mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a similar question [Copy the contents of a file into the clipboard without displaying its contents - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211817/copy-the-contents-of-a-file-into-the-clipboard-without-displaying-its-contents) :

Install [`xclip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xclip.1.html) using:

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

To copy the script:

```
xclip -sel c < yourfile.html
```

To copy the text (suggested by [KJA](https://askubuntu.com/users/723218/kja) in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227725/using-command-line-to-copy-html-file-to-clipboard#comment2066701_1227729)):

```
xclip -t text/html -sel c < filename.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply
This does not add the file as text/html
I found the following solution
xclip -t text/html -sel c < filename.html

Comment: OK Nixe to knowledge

Comment: This works very well at the moment and is best choice among others